# Today's CSS update broke flag page

Tags: bug, status-completed, flag-history

There is extra white space or border (I can't tell which one is new), which doesn't look so nice, but the main problem is the overflow of the post's score. The number is either displaced (e.g. 5th report) or completely hidden behind the title (e.g. 3rd & 4th report).

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure I checked this page without any userscripts running and can confirm the same bug. Using Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: A developer is currently working on this. Turns out the same CSS update affected a number of things in the UI. All should be back to normal shortly. See also: https://twitter.com/aalear/status/1236031982141874188

Comment: I made a joke about [testing in production](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344858/incorrect-highlighting-deleted-posts-in-profile#comment1155550_344858) but reality took over ;)  ... poor Adam ...

Comment: @Cody "shortly" has passed... guess it will be the usual 6-8 days/weeks/moths like any non-critical bug?

Comment: I think it turned out to be...what's that word developers have nightmares about? Oh yeah, *complicated*. @sha

Comment: @Cody ugh... I'm just in the middle of simple-ish change that developed into a week+ nightmare, so no need to tell me about it. Just hoped the CSS isn't at such risk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry about that. Turned out we used the `.deleted-answer` style in far more places than just the question page itself. I deployed a round of fixes earlier today. The main thing I'm aware of that's missing from that is the flag dialog S.S. Anne mentions in their answer. I have a fix for that ready as well, and it should go out tomorrow.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thanks for the work! Looking forward to seeing the result.

Comment: @S.S.Anne The flag dialog fix is live now.

Comment: I don't know if the flag dialog broke the flag-history page or if it wasn't fixed fully, but the long title is still not right. See the 5th report in the original question.

Comment: @Dharman Whoops, good catch! The fix for that is in the queue to go to production with the next build.

Answer (score 6):

This CSS update *also* broke the flag dialog:

[image]

Please test these things before pushing them to the site.